# How do I append a colon zero, :0 onto the end of an IP address string?

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell

I have a simple Linux shell script that parses a file generated in windows that is shared with a Linux VM. I would like to obtain an IP address from this file and append a colon 0 (:0) on the end, so as to set the DISPLAY environment variable. When I try to do so, I get strange results.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOCAL_HOST=`grep IPv4 /mnt/hgfs/share/localip | awk 'NR ==1 {printf "%s\n", $14 }'`

# for some reason, it overwrites the string from the beginning
COLON_ZERO=':0'
export DISPLAY=${LOCAL_HOST}${COLON_ZERO}
echo $DISPLAY

# This obviously works, but doesnt have the COLON_ZERO on the end
echo "export DISPLAY="$LOCAL_HOST
```

And here is the output of running this script:

```
# ./display.sh
:09.107.26.25
export DISPLAY=159.107.26.25

# bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

And just in case its necessary, here is the result of the grep from the file used in the script:

```
# grep IPv4 /mnt/hgfs/share/localip
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 159.107.26.25
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.223.1
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.132.1
```

Why do I get this strange result when I append the colon zero onto the end of the IP address string? How can I change the script to get the correct result?

Comment: Why `echo "export DISPLAY="$LOCAL_HOST` if you want to `echo $DISPLAY`?

Comment: @pizza, yes its for x windows, to be able to send a gnome-terminal to a Windows display using XMing.

Comment: @Tichodroma, Im just doing the echo for debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input file contains Windows line endings (\r\n). Remove the \r character from the ip address.

Comment: Specifically, `LOCAL_HOST=\`tr -d '\015' < /mnt/hgfs/share/localip | awk '/IPv4/ {printf "%s\n", $14 ; exit(0)}'\`` assuming the input file has DOS line endings. Note also the refactoring to avoid the `grep | awk` antipattern.

Comment: That was the problem, I did a dos2unix and ran the script again and it works as expected. @tripleee, I'll test your suggestion now, thanks.